# Source ~/.vim directory from another location than home directory

Tags: macos, vim, configuration, startup

To install `~/.vimrc` on a system-wide level, I execute `vim --version` and look where I can put it.

But what steps do I have to take in order to change the location of the `/.vim` directory containing e.g. *autoload* with *pathogen*, *plugins*, etc.? The more I think about it, the less I understand why it is sourced at startup anyhow.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? If you want your beloved plugins and all when working as root, use `$ sudo -e filename`.

Comment: Why do you want to choose? What's wrong with `~/.vim/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look the `/etc/vimrc` and `/usr/share/vim` or `/usr/share/vim74` But it is not good to change those files. Because next time you upgrade vim, those files could be overwritten by your package manager, unless you do this manually or never update vim.

#### edit

Just noticed that the question was tagged with `osx`.... the above text is based on linux. If it doesn't help, I am gonna remove it.

Comment: The files you say are in `/usr/share/vim`, for me, are in `/usr/local/share/vim`, so it's OK.